# Possible CSS background image bug in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

On the following website (www.orba.com), the white text that is overlaying the blue and green panels is not displaying on Firefox 44.0 on PC. It displays fine in all other browsers. This problem was not occurring 6 months ago. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: It might be a bug. But without a [mcve] your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

caused by [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode). It seems to be yet an an experimental technology :

```
.panel .title, c {
    ...
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    ...
}
```

Remove it or set it to `horizontal-tb` (*its default value*) and text will show up back.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bug. A minimal testcase is

```css
body, .first {
  height: 200px;
}
.first {
  margin-top: 1px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
```

In your page you use the deprecated `writing-mode: tb-rl`, which [bug 1205787](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1205787) aliased to `writing-mode: vertical-rl`.

But it seems that this specific mix of height, margin, writing-mode and float doesn't work well after [bug 1144501](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1144501).

I have filed [bug 1243125](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1243125) to fix this.

Comment: Great test case ! I tried but I wasn't able to reproduce the bug within a minimal example. it seems like as you said the specific mix of height, margin, writing-mode and float is causing it. the code snippet works in Chrome but not in Firefox.